# Magento 2 - How to use custom JS

Tags: javascript, requirejs-config.js

Why can't I call my custom `test()` method?

## Attempt 1

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
    function test()
    {
        alert("it works!");
    }
});
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/forms/default.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test'], function() {
        test();
    });
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

---

## Attempt 2

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
    function test()
    {
        alert("it works!");
    }
});
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/forms/default.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test'], function(script) {
        script.test();
    });
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')
```

---

## Attempt 3

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
    return function test()
    {
        alert("it works!");
    }
});
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/forms/default.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test'], function(script) {
        script.test();
    });
</script>
```

**Output:**

```
contacts:2958 Uncaught TypeError: script.test is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/web/js/test.js**

```
function test()
{
    alert("it works!");
}
```

**app/code/Company/Test/view/frontend/templates/forms/default.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['Company_Test/js/test'], function() {
        test();
    });
</script>
```